# Error connecting to SQL host, PHP Script: PHPVALLEY Microjob Script

Tags: php, mysql, database, hosting, cpanel

I installed the php script and all wen well but the problem is at the final step, when I need to fill the database information, when I field the database information I find that i am getting an error that says "**Error connecting to SQL host**", so I try and try in different ways but there is no solution, nevertheless, I installed the same script on my **localhost** and all went well without problems, my Hosting Provider is: Siteground

Filling Database Information Image
[image]
Showing the Error Image
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must grant write permissions to the connect.php file for the user who is running the web service for example apache.

Have you ssh access to the server?

Answer (score 1):

If your application cannot connect to the database you should make sure that:

- Your application is using the correct MySQL hostname: localhost
- Your application is using the correct MySQL database / username /
  password.
- Don't forget to specify your MySQL username and database with the
  prefix yourusername_ in front of its given name. For example, your
  cPanel username is siteground and you have named your database
  joomla. In this case you have to refer to your database as
  siteground_joomla;

Source: https://www.siteground.com/kb/my_script_cannot_connect_to_my_database_/

Another good idea would be to try to use your cPanel username and password for the Database User and Database Password. This will rule out whether you have granted all privileges to your database user.

Also you should change the permissions of your connect.php file to 755, as if you set them to 777, this will cause an internal server error.